# Retrofit2+RxAndroid execute many requests in a loop

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android

I use RxAndroid library + Retrofit2.

I Have 2 post requests:

1. Get all category (return List == each String is category id)
2. Get ProductsByCategory (return List)

I need load all products and save to DB after start App.

When I create MainFragment I get all Categories:

```
restApiFactory.getProductService().getCategories(new CategoryRequest(initiatorId))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new CategoriesHandler());
```

and Handle response:

```
@Override
    public void onNext(CategoryResponse value) {
        List<CategoryItem> categoryItems = value.getCategoryItems();
        ...
    }
```

And then I need send another request(`ProductsByCategory` ) but I not understand how do it?

I can send it in foreach:

```
for (CategoryItem categoryItem : categoryItems) {
             Observable<Products> product =  ProductsByCategory...
            }
```

or maby there is some Observable merge ....

I do not know. In general, how to do this? two requests to the server. one will return the list of id and the second product on these id.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using flaMap in rxjava
This is example demonstrate snippet how to implement it

```
api.serviceA()
        .flatMap(new Func1<FooA, Observable<FooB>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<FooB> call(FooA fooA) {
                // code to save data from service A to db

                // call service B
                return api.serviceB();
            }
         })
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .subscribe(new Subscriber<FooB>() {
             @Override
             public void onCompleted() {
             }

             @Override
             public void onError(Throwable e) {

             }

             @Override
             public void onNext(FooB fooB) {
                 // code to save data from service B to db

             }
        });
```

Comment: Additionally: you can also use `flatMap` to convert a `List<T>` into an `Observable<T>`

Comment: He has a list from previous call and need to call api again with each element from that list, can't do like this;

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Iterable`, call api with `CategoryItem` and then use `toList()` in order to obtain a list of `ProductsByCategory`.